# Convert base64 data into decimal

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
CANMIC_BASE64_DATA="FxEYEhkTGhQbFRwWIQcBCAIJAwoECwUMBjEHAQgCCQMKBAsFDAYAgICAgICAgICAgICAAICAgICAgICAgICAgAu003du003d"
CANMIC_HEX_DATA=$(base64 -d -i <<<$CANMIC_BASE64_DATA | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x," ')
```

I get hex data in `CANMIC_BASE64_DATA*` and then store this data into array

```
array_len=${#array[@]}
```

Once I store it into array it store it as decimal. But I was it should be in hex only in array. I need to convert `base64` into decimal similar to `CANMIC_HEX_DATA` dumping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your base64 encoded string, you can assign each byte to an array.

Either you assign the array with hexadecimal values:

```
arr1=($(base64 -d <<< "FxEYEhkTGhQbFRwWIQcBCAIJAwoECwUMBjEHAQgCCQMKBAsFDAYAgICAgICAgICAgICAAICAgICAgICAgICAgAu003du003d" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "0x%02x " '))
printf "%s" "${arr1[0]}"
0x17
printf "%d" "${arr1[0]}"
23
printf "%x" "${arr1[0]}"
17
```

Either you assign your array with decimal values:

```
arr2=($(base64 -d <<< "FxEYEhkTGhQbFRwWIQcBCAIJAwoECwUMBjEHAQgCCQMKBAsFDAYAgICAgICAgICAgICAAICAgICAgICAgICAgAu003du003d" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02d " '))
$ printf "%s" "${arr2[0]}"
23
$ printf "%d" "${arr2[0]}"
23
$ printf "%x" "${arr2[0]}"
17
```

The only difference is the `hexdump` format.

Note that you can't deal with binary directly with variable as the shell will refuse to accept it.

For example, with bash, trying `var="$(echo -e "\x00")"` will result in the error `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`